# Insert custom attribute in chunks with angular cli project

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, html-webpack-plugin

i have a angular v11 solution with CLI. I've added this line in the angular.json to be able to extend the webpack with my custom implementation

```
 "customWebpackConfig": {
   "path": "config/webpack.dev.js",
   "replaceDuplicatePlugins": false
 }
```

And this is my custom webpack

```
 const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
 const ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');
 module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
        new ScriptExtHtmlWebpackPlugin({
            custom: {
                test: /\.js$/,
                attribute: 'data-ot-ignore'
            }
        }),
    ]
};
```

I want to add custom attribute in the index.html after the build is done. But the implementation above is not working.

This is what i want:

[image]

is it possible to do it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using [IndexTransform](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/blob/master/packages/custom-webpack/README.md#index-transform)

```
// add attribue to skip oneTrust blocking script
  indexHtml = indexHtml.replace('src="runtime', 'data-ot-ignore src="runtime');

return indexHtml;
```